# What is the best method/software to log from a Windows 2008 server to your standard (syslog) loghost?

Tags: windows, syslog

Centralized logging is a good thing, and all unix/linux/bsd machines are able to syslog over udp/tcp. Windows servers have the event log.

I've previously used NTSyslog (http://ntsyslog.sf.net) for this, but I'm wondering if there are better solutions.

The primary goals are to log login attempts (auditing), software and hardware errors.

Are there better methods than syslog for this? Is there a better syslog client for windows around?

Answer (score 1):

We use SNARE also and send everything to a centralized syslog host running LogZilla (http://www.logzilla.pro) which allows us to search and do graphs, charts, etc. It's also extremly fast - we log over 200m events a day and searches still return results in 1-3 seconds depending on system load.

Answer (score 0):

We've used SNARE with good results (another syslog client for windows)

http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/SnareWindows/